# Disable Cache in the angular ui-grid (ui-grid.info)

Tags: angularjs, caching, angular-ui-grid

I want to disable cache on angular [ui grid](http://ui-grid.info/). How can I do it? It is not mentioned in the documentation or tutorials.

I already have tried this:

```
$(function () {
   console.log("ready!"); //Disable Local Cache 
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
});
```

Comment: I had to add multiple header values as specified in this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers

Answer (score 0):

How are providing data to ui-grid? You have to disable caching in the place from where you getting the data. If you are using `$http` then you can pass the `no-cache` header along with the request.

E.g.

```
$http.get( 'url' , { headers: { 'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache' } } );
```

If you are using `ajax` then whatever you have commented in the question should work fine.

Comment: Even after adding the above header in my $http.get call, it still loads the values from cache in my angular grid.  
Also, the code I have in my question does not helps in angular grid, but it helps on the other pages with my client AJAX requests.